# ActionView::Template::Error (uninitialized constant `LibObject`):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, function, class, model

I have added a object to the lib folder.
And it's working well first time, but if I modify the controller or model, then it says `Uninitialized constant error`....

This is lib/lib_object.rb

```
class LibObject
    def object_description
    "object description"
  end
end
```

And it's calling from model.

```
def object_description
  return LibObject.new.object_description
end
```

I am not sure, why I am getting the `uninitialized constant error` after modification for some code...
So I need to restart the server every time(updates code) .
Thank you.

Comment: Can you paste the entire error?

Answer (score 1):

This can be added in your `config/application.rb` to load your `lib/` directory:

```
config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

Restart your local server after adding this.

Keep in mind that if you use [autoload_paths](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoload-paths-and-eager-load-paths):

> But using autoload_paths on its own in the past (pre-rails 5) developers might configure autoload_paths to add in extra locations (e.g. lib which used to be an autoload path list years ago, but no longer is). However this is now discouraged for most purposes, as it is likely to lead to production-only errors.